# how to a website SSL certificate is valid or not?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I got an issue from my client regarding the SSL setup for his website. I'm not familiar with the SSL certification setup process. He is saying that `We have an SSL certificate for this server but I can’t tell if it’s setup properly or not`.

If I open that website, firefox says `Warning: Contains unauthorized content`. I am seeing some details in the warning message window which are given below:

```
Web site: mydomain.com
Owner: This web site does not supply ownership information
Verified by: Not specified
```

Mainly I want to know whether the SSL certificate used for this site is valid or not. Can anybody suggest a way to check for the SSL certificate validation of a website.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide OS and webserver name ?

Comment: OS is Windows and my webserver is Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telnet the server on port 443. If it is responding then it is a certificate problem

To install certificate 
Check [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/tomcat-ssl-howto.html)

Comment: Thanks Manjoor, your comment helped me to fix my issue. I found a website(http://www.digicert.com/help/) to check the SSL certificate of any site using the server address, is this the correct way to check SSL?

Comment: Yes it is fine. If your problem has been resolved, please mark the question as answered. It'll increase your acceptance ratio. Give some time and learn how stackoverflow works http://stackoverflow.com/faq